# Provide DB configuration details w/o config.yml using DropWizard?

Tags: java, web-services, dropwizard

I've developed a webservice using DropWizard framework.

The database configuration file for it is config.yml.

Is there any other way to provide the configuration details?

I do now want to use config.yml file in my code. Is it an option ?

I tried to go through the dropwizard docs but could not find any word on this. Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you don't want to use the yaml configuration?

You could always create your own `DataSourceFactory` and populate it from another configuration source (or in the code, which I would not recommend):

```java
DataSourceFactory factory = new DataSourceFactory();
factory.setUrl(someJdbcUrl);
factory.setUser("foo");
factory.setPassword("bar");
```

Comment: I have to connect to multiple databases with different usercredentials... the creds are passed over to the webservice and the creds are used for connection. Why is it not a recommended thing?

Comment: I just meant that storing credentials in your source files isn't suggested. If you pass them in via a web service then make sure you're securing that in some fashion.

Comment: I understand. One last question on the solution you suggested, Is this part of dropwizard framework? Or do i hve to get some extra jars?

Comment: I thought that you were using the [dropwizard managed hibernate support](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/hibernate.html). If the credentials are being sent in per resource invocation you might want to consider something like [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/) (which dropwizard also supports, incidentally).